# Using sprintf (or other alternative) to name a written table in R

Tags: r, printf

I am writing a function in **R** that will write a data frame to a table. Each time I call the function, I would like to name that table after the name of the data file imported. I am familiar with `eval` and `sprintf` from my experience with Matlab, but I am learning **R** and wondering what alternatives are available (I know eval is evIl!).

```
txtfile='datafileA.txt';  #name of data text file 
statsdf<-as.data.frame(stats)  #data frame that I would like to write to a table
txtname=str_sub(txtfile,1,-5)  #portion of text file that I would like to name my table after
#my attempt at naming the table written after the data file:
sprintf("write.table(statsdf,'Stats_%s.txt',sep='\t',col.names=NA,quote=FALSE)",txtname)
```

How do I run the command above?
Is there a better way to do this in **R**?

Comment: Other alternatives: `paste`, `substitute`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
filename <- sprintf("Stats_%s.txt", txtname)

write.table(statsdf, file = filename, sep = "\t", col.names = NA, quote = FALSE)
```

Comment: @NicoleGoebel feel free to mark it as the selected answer if it solved your problem

Comment: Thanks for letting me know to do that. I am knew to SE.